# What is the duration between: the moment we stop breathing and to body's and involuntary mucle movement?

Tags: human-physiology, behaviour, breathing, reflexes

I studied that if someone stops breathing by pressing their nostrils with fingers and start to starve without oxygen, the body will automatically cause the hands to leave the nostrils in a **certain time** so that we can breathe. (a kind of reflex, I guess)

What is this certain time?

Comment: Could you include a source for where you studied that? Thanks.

Comment: I found it in many sources, one is https://www.healthline.com/health/holding-your-breath#what-happens

Comment: Have u seen the above comment @user438383

Comment: The link you gave doesn't say anything at all about the body "automatically" causing the hands to leave the nostrils. That will happen when you black out, as your muscles become flaccid and gravity causes your hand to move away from your face, but there's no "automatic" movement...

Answer (score 2):

Your respiratory system has quite a number of neural and non-neural (e.g., physical, emotional, and chemical factors) [controls](https://courses.lumenlearning.com/boundless-ap/chapter/respiration-control) in addition to the ability to be voluntary controlled.

- A strong influence on much of our respiratory physiology is a response to changes in carbon dioxide in the blood (well, more specifically, it's [blood pH](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK482456/) that is regulated).  Oxygen [homeostasis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homeostasis) is also controlled.

As a result, the duration you're asking about almost certainly is dependent on [total lung capacity](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK541029/#:%7E:text=Lung%20capacity%20or%20total%20lung,capacity%20is%20about%206%20liters.), actual volume of air inhaled, [diffusion capacities](https://medlineplus.gov/ency/article/003854.htm), [activity levels](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4818249), etc. as each of these would determine levels of oxygen and CO<sub>2</sub> in the blood and available to tissues (such as the brain).

- In other words, since gas homeostasis plays such a prominent role in respiratory control, the duration of any "reflex" response would vary between person to person (based on their anatomy) and even for an individual person based on circumstances.

Also, I'm not personally familiar with any such *reflex* that you mention.*

- In fact, some children intentionally hold their breath *until they pass out*! This passing out is actually a useful adaptation because it allows the body to return to using involuntary breathing controls to prevent the child from depriving themselves of oxygen long enough to induce death. [Seattle Children's Hospital](https://www.seattlechildrens.org/conditions/a-z/breath-holding-spell/) suggests normal breathing returns in under 2 minutes.
- Also see the [fainting game](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Choking_game) that got popular among teens earlier this century that involved intentionally causing self [syncope](https://my.clevelandclinic.org/health/diseases/17536-syncope). [WARNING: DON'T BE THIS STUPID]

<sup>* If you can update your question with a source or any additional information about the "reflex" you mention, I or someone else might be able to address the reflex or your source of info more specifically.</sup>